# Maven - Serenity - JBehave (BDD Framework) - Not getting index.html report files

Tags: serenity-bdd

I am using `Maven+Serenity+JBehave` framework in which I am facing issue with report generation.

I am getting `JBehave` report inside `/target/jbehave/view/index.html` and `/target/jbehave/view/report.html` but the report is not fully formatted.

I want to generate serenity report inside `/target/site/serenity/index.html` which is not happening now. I am only able to get images and other files but not `index.html`.

I tried with a different version of `serenity-core` and `serenity-reports` group but even then it is not working.

Can anyone please look into it?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now.

What I did to resolve?
Serenity version : 1.8.20 (It is old version but using latest version throws an exception)
Serenity maven version : 1.8.20 
serenity-core : 1.8.20

Run as -> Maven Build

Its working fine now and able to get index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try add

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

i tried and it worked